# How to analyze my own transmitted Bluetooth signal on Android

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, indoor-positioning-system

I want to create an Android app where I want to be able to receive my own transmitter Bluetooth signal in Android , since Bluetooth signal is omnidirectional. 
I.e. I want to receive and transmit Bluetooth at same time and receive my own transmitted signal and analyze it on same phone.

Or I tried to use beacon simulator to simulate LE beacon Bluetooth signal and in my Bluetooth setting I tried to scan for available devices but it does not show my android device.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to simultaneously transmit and receive the same packets from the same antenna systems. Theoretically, you can receive packets resulting from reflections. In the practice, this application has no right to work. Switching the operating mode from the transmitter to the radio receiver requires time.

To track bluetooth packets you can use the CC2640 dongle with the PC application:

http://www.ti.com/tool/PACKET-SNIFFER

Comment: But when two Bluetooth devices are connected, they are able to send and receive data at same time.

Comment: I just want to scan for my transmitted Bluetooth packets from same device , not pair just analyze it ( Its RSSI, etc after reflection and before reflection)

Comment: Not at the same time. Generally it works on a ping-pong basis. Without a second device, you cannot determine the RSSI level. To begin with, you can read about the theory of radio waves and the basics of bluetooth low energy.

If you want to try in practice, try to mix exmaples with simple ble scanner and beacon in one Android app. On Google and yt you will find plenty of fundamental examples.

Comment: Yes, on ping pong basis, I tried to run beacon and Bluetooth scanner on same phone. But Bluetooth scanner does not shows anything

Comment: To do what you want you need two devices one scanning and the other advertising packets. The second solution is one device with two bluetooth systems, then one serves as a receiver and the other as a transmitter.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot. Is it possible to reduce beacon signal range after simulating BLE on Android. I want to create an Android application to work like Bluetooth LE with small range like 2m

Comment: The easiest way will be to restrict RSSI. And discard read devices below defined level. You will need to determine the limit value by measuring your devices. Also pay attention to the arrangement of devices relative to each other, the signals will differ due to the attenuating elements and the characteristics of the antennas.